# Environment variables in docker-compose are substituted as empty string

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Though having read the Docker documentation about environment variables I have some trouble understanding the variable substitution.

This is my current `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    image: myimage:latest
    environment:
      FRONTEND_URL: http://mydomain
      CALLBACK_URL: ${FRONTEND_URL}/callback
```

My understanding so far is that I can use something like `${FRONTEND_URL}` so that `CALLBACK_URL` will be interpolated to `http://mydomain/callback`, but after a `docker-compose up` this service has the following environment values:

```
FRONTEND_URL: http://mydomain
CALLBACK_URL: /callback
```

So it looks as if `${FRONTEND_URL}` is not substituted. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `.env` file on the same folder a `docker-compose.yml`.

**.env**

```
FRONTEND_URL=http://mydomain
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    image: myimage:latest
    environment:
      FRONTEND_URL: ${FRONTEND_URL}
      CALLBACK_URL: ${FRONTEND_URL}/callback
```

[image]

---

Instead of using the `.env` file you can use `export`. Run this command before `docker-compose up`:

```
export FRONTEND_URL=http://mydomain
```

Now you can use this `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    image: myimage:latest
    environment:
      FRONTEND_URL: ${FRONTEND_URL}
      CALLBACK_URL: ${FRONTEND_URL}/callback
```

---

> If an environment variable is not set, Compose substitutes with an empty string. In the example above, if `POSTGRES_VERSION` is not set, the value for the image option is `postgres:`.
>
> You can set default values for environment variables using a [`.env` file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/), which Compose automatically looks for. Values set in the shell environment override those set in the `.env` file.
>
> **source:** https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So if I get this right, then it's not possible defining an environment variable *inside* a compose file and then reuse this in the same or another compose file?

Comment: Yes it is not possible at the moment. Also have a look here: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3435